# Nested quotion and expanding

Tags: macros, clojure

Lets say i have fn `begin`: `(begin "hello")`. The result of `` `(begin "hello") `` will be `(my-ns/begin "hello")`. It's good. But now I do this: `(def x '(begin "hello"))`. How can I expand `x` with backquote to get `(my-ns/begin "hello")`, not just `(begin "hello")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you used `` ` `` which is a reader macro named "syntax-quote", In the second example you used `'` Which is a reader macro named "quote". Syntax-quote offers a couple of features beyond what `quote` offers:

- unquoting with `~`, `~@`, etc
- namespace expansion of symbols for use in writing hygenic macros.

Plain old `quote` does neither of these. So if you want namespace expansion in both examples use `` ` `` in both places. If you want to get an un-namespaced symbol in a syntax-quooted list you can use both of them together `` `(println ~'symbol-name) `` which will evaluate to simply `(println symbol-name)`. (in this case symbol-name needs to be defined in the namespace where this is called (this process in known as "symbol capture")). The syntax-quote evaluates first to a call to quote, when in turn evaluates to the symbol.

If you are looking to expand a symbol that already exists for some reason, or you want to expand it in several different namespaces that both define it, you can use the `ns-resolve` function:

```
(ns-resolve *ns* 'begin)
```

so in your example you can map this over the list to print it with the NS qualified symbols:

```
user> (map #(if (symbol? %) (ns-resolve *ns*  %) %) x)
(#'user/begin "hello")
```

Though this is not *exactly* the desired output because it refers to the var in that namespace rather than the symbol that resolves to this var. Things get a little dicey here because `` ` `` is a reader macro and we can't build calls to it in other macros. For instance I can think of no way to write:

```
(defmacro expand-x [thing] 
  `(syntax-quote-here ~thing)
```

Because as far as I know syntax-quote doesn't have a name (again because it is a reader macro) so there is nothing to use in place of syntax-quote-here in the above example. Though never fear, in a language with `eval` nothing is impossible, things just get arbitrarily ugly:

```
user> (eval (read-string (str "`" x)))
(user/begin "hello")
```

PS: don't actually use this last example or gremlins will inhabit your code for all time

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I'll fix this in a moment

Comment: thank you for `ns-resolve`. I tried to know how to map namespaces to the symbols when I pass the form to macro: http://pastebin.com/0SHKh87r

Comment: p.s. in this particular example i can just use `defn` instead of `def` to solve my problem, thanks #clojure IRC =)